# android retrieve attribute from xml layout (or retrieving paddingStart value in Android < 17)

Tags: android, right-to-left

I'm trying to do a function to handle RTL on android < 17.

My idea is on create of each activity/fragment,  loop on fields, and if the direction should be RTL i retrieve the values of `paddingStart/paddingEnd`, `marginStart/marginEnd`..... and replace them with the corresponding values of `paddingLeft/paddingRight`, `marginLeft/marginRight`

Is there a way to retrieve these info since getPaddingStart() doesn't exist ?

Also if you have any suggestions or ideas for a better way to handle RTL.

Thanks,

Comment: You can use the ViewCompat class https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewCompat.html#getPaddingStart(android.view.View)

Comment: @Luksprog wow this is perfect, anything similar for XML ? If I can include a compat library and have RTL working alone it would be perfect :D